# DB2 connection broken between consecutive JNI calls to C++ DLLs

Tags: java, c++, connection, db2-luw

I'm using a Java batch application to call the service method of a legacy application via jni. This application consists of various c++ DLLs using embedded static sql.

A first jni call starts and configures the legacy application, subsequent calls concern the service method, and finally the application is shut down with a final call.
With each call of the service method, various SQL statements (vs. IBM DB2 LUW) are executed, distributed over the various DLLs of the legacy application.

Everything works perfectly as long as I open and close a DB-connection every time I call the service method.
But since the connect turned out to be a major performance issue (a run will contain between 1.5 and 2 million legacy calls), I would like to establish the connection once with the first call and close it with the last one.
But apparently the connection is not held between the jni calls, since successive calls (of the service method) lead to corresponding sqlcode errors (-1024). As long as i don't leave the c++-area, the connection is active; it is closed every time i return to the java application.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get along with exactly 1 connect/disconnect. I'm somehow running out of ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you hook the dll and override the comnect/disconnect methods witb something that just returns a cached handle?

Comment: I have to admit that I not yet really get your idea. What would the cached handle be?

Comment: Whatever was returned from the very first connect call.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing returned from the connect call. With embedded SQL in C++ there is no connection object as in java. You execute the connect statement to establish the connection and that's it.

Comment: Even better! Then you can replace the connect function with something like `if (already_connected) return; do_original_connection(); already_connected = true;` and make the disconnect function a no_op.

Comment: I apologize, maybe I did not describe my problem properly.
The suggested solution was my original approach and is exactly what doesn't work.
I don't have to prevent the connect from being executed unnecessarily, my problem is that the connect is actually necessary, since the connection is closed by DB2 without my intervention.
With static SQL, the connection is normally established at the beginning and remains active until the end of the application. In my JNI scenario every return to the Java application seems to be considered "end of application", which leads to implicit closure.

Comment: Right, I was referring to overriding the native code that does the connection and disconnection, not on the Java side.